# ActiveRecord many to many associations behavior after destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a database with models: `App` and `ContentCategory`.
Each app could have several content categories and vice versa.

Also, I have join table as `ContentCategoryOwnership`

```
class ContentCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :content_category_ownerships, inverse_of: :content_category, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :apps, through: :content_category_ownerships
    attr_accessible(
        :title
        )
    validates :title, uniqueness: :true
end

class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :app_targetings, inverse_of: :app
  has_many :campaigns, through: :app_targetings
  has_many :app_ownerships
  has_many :users, through: :app_ownerships


  has_many :content_category_ownerships, inverse_of: :app, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :content_categories, through: :content_category_ownerships
end

class ContentCategoryOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :content_category
    belongs_to :app
    has_many :content_category_targetings, inverse_of: :content_category_ownership, dependent: :destroy
end

it 'is expected to be deleted consistently' do
    fashion = create :content_category, title: 'fashion'
    motors = create :content_category, title: 'motors'
    app = create :app
    another_app = create :app
    app.content_categories << [fashion, motors]
    another_app.content_categories << fashion

    fashion.destroy
    expect(fashion).to be_destroyed

    expect(app.content_categories).to contain_exactly(motors) # not removed?
    expect(another_app.content_categories).to be_empty # not removed? ( empty - false, still contains fashion category )
    expect(another_app.content_categories.pluck(:title)).to be_empty # true!
end
```

I see behavior as 'caching' associations results. So, if you leave associations alone `another_app.content_categories`, you will see that this association still contains removed object ( `fashion` category ). And if you add, for example, `pluck` method, you will see empty result.

I need explanation about this behavior, maybe I miss documentation point.

Rails console example:

```
 app = App.new
 app.id = 42
 content_category = ContentCategory.new
 content_category.id = 42
 app.content_categories << content_category
 app.content_categories
 content_category.destroy
 app.content_categories.empty? # ( false )
 app.content_categories # still exists?
 app.content_categories.pluck(:id).empty? # true!
```

Information:

- Active Record 4.2.1
- Rails 4.2.1
- Ruby 2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `content_categories` are cached in  the instances of `app` and `another_app` when you destroy them the cache will not reflect this change.

What you need to do is `reload` the objects e.g.

```
it 'is expected to be deleted consistently' do
    fashion = create :content_category, title: 'fashion'
    motors = create :content_category, title: 'motors'
    app = create :app
    another_app = create :app
    app.content_categories << [fashion, motors]
    another_app.content_categories << fashion

    fashion.destroy
    expect(fashion).to be_destroyed
    app.reload
    another_app.reload
    expect(app.content_categories).to contain_exactly(motors) # removed
    expect(another_app.content_categories).to be_empty #removed
    expect(another_app.content_categories.pluck(:title)).to be_empty 
end
```

The reason `pluck` works is that it does not rely on the cached values but rather runs a query against the database to pull the titles and when it checks the database there are no longer any `ContentCategories` with an `app_id` that matches the given instances `id`.